# (jQuery) How to grab two divs and insert them on a new div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm very newbie with jQuery (and Javascript) and i don't know how to do this.

I want to grab two divs and insert them on a new div.

Example:

```
 <div class="test"></div>
 <div class="test"></div>
 <div class="test2"></div>
 <div class="test2"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="float">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>

<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

```
 $('div.test').wrapAll( "<div class='float'></div>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use "wrapAll"

```
$('div.test').wrapAll('<div class="float"/>');
```

(**edited** because I'm feeble-minded sometimes)

Comment: wrap is the preferred way, yes

Comment: I love how jQuery is so terse.

Comment: Except that this will wrap each element individually, not as a group.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div/>', {
  class:   'float',
  css:     {
     position: 'relative',
     display:  'block'
  }
}).append($('.test')).prependTo('body');
```

should do the trick, but untested.

Comment: I just said to myself.. "why doing it easy if there is a hard way?".. :p so, I guess tvanfossons answer is best for that.